# Joomla Media Manager Not working - Server error 500

Tags: joomla-3.x, php, joomla-3.3.x, server

Good evening,

Can anyone shed some light on this issue? I had to restore our website from a Backup, once finished the MEDIA MANAGER and some images stopped working. Server Error 500 shows up : (

I tried reseting the permissions and fixed the `.htaccess` file but I had no luck.

Could you please advise?

Here's some info:

```
PHP Built On    Linux web905.opentransfer.com 
Database Version    5.1.68-community-log
Database Collation  utf8_general_ci
PHP Version     5.3.29
Web Server  Apache
WebServer to PHP Interface  cgi-fcgi
Joomla! Version     Joomla! 3.3.1 Stable [ Ember ] 11-June-2014 13:30 GMT
Joomla! Platform Version    Joomla Platform 13.1.0 Stable [ Curiosity ] 24-Apr-2013 00:00 GMT
```

THANK YOU!

Comment: What is the exact Server Error 500 Message?

Comment: Thanks. The error has no details. Just 'Server error 500'. 

On firefox the screen goes blank. The issue can be seen in the administration area, when trying to access the Media Manager. 

On Chrome this message shows up: 

The website encountered an error while retrieving http://inkarri.pt/administrator/index.php?option=com_remoteimage. It may be down for maintenance or configured incorrectly.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This installation is not working correctly. When updating Joomla! I get the error message: Warning
Error loading component: com_remoteimage, Component not found

Update: :Extension: Could not open https://update.joomla.org/core/sts/extension_sts.xml

Error loading component: com_remoteimage, Component not found

Update: :Extension: Could not open https://update.joomla.org/core/sts/extension_sts.xml

Are you a Joomla! dev? WOuld you give an estimate if so? We just need help with this issues asap. : ) Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Your comment above `On Chrome this message shows up: The website encountered an error while retrieving inkarri.pt/administrator/index.php?option=com_remoteimage. It may be down for maintenance or configured incorrectly.` leads me to conclusion that this problem is caused by an extension and not by core Joomla, because core Joomla doesn't have `com_remoteimage` but `com_media`.

Google tells me there was an extension called 'Remote & Local Image Manager' bit it is now defunct and [unpublsihed from JED](http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/photos-a-images/images/remote-local-image-manager).

I'd say to go to Extensions | Manage and look for some similar extension, either unpublish it or uninstall it, and your built-in Media Manager might be back and working.

On side note, I see that you are running Joomla v3.3.1. There is a critical security vulnerability with [all versions of Joomla lower that 3.4.7](http://joomla.org/announcements/release-news/5643-joomla-3-4-7.html)  You should update your site immediately to v3.4.8, which is latest J! version at the moment.

Comment: Thanks Mirko! I disabled the 'RemoteImage' Extension but it looks like it was being used as the default or built-in media manager. I got the following error message. 404 Component not found. When trying to access Media Manager. I will try to update J! hopefully nothing else will break. Thanks again.

Comment: Additionally, how can I enable the built-in Media Manager?

Comment: Of course you will get that message if you only disabled plugin and leave component enabled. You should uninstall component from Manage Extensions and that should re-enable built-in Media Manager. It is anyway gone for good, if JED listing shows it as PE1 (Broken Links).

Comment: I uninstalled the Plug in however, the following message shows up on Front and back end: 
Warning
Error loading component: com_remoteimage, Component not found
It didn't work as expected. How can I revert or bring back the built-in media manager?